# How to clone an Object without knowing the exact type in Java?

Tags: java, object, clone

```
public void test(Object obj){`
      Object newObj = obj;//reference

}
```

Without knowing the exact type of obj, how could I clone it such as something as 
`Object newObj = obj.clone();` or `Object newObj = new Object(obj);`

The actual situation is: in a class `Message` I set a member `HashMap<String,Object>` to allow anyone which wanna use `Message` can add other properties/members instead of rewriting it. The object may be `ArrarList<Integer>`. Here comes the problem.

Comment: Why do you think it is useful to clone an object if you don't know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

A safe way is to serialize the object, then deserialize. This ensures everything is a brand new reference. You'll have to implement the `Serializable` interface.

Google commons class `org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils` provides this for you via the following method:

```
SerializationUtils.clone(Object);
```

Example:

```
this.myObjectCloned = SerializationUtils.clone(this.object);
```

Comment: but in this case `object instanceof java.io.Serializable` must return true

Comment: Except that this requires the object to be serializeable. And even when it is - there are no guarantees whatsoever that the complete internal state will be serialized.

Comment: @lukaslew I quoted the same in the answer 
`You'll have to implement the Serializable interface.`

Comment: @GhostCat Yeah, I've mentioned the clause of serialization in the answer. `You'll have to implement the Serializable interface.`. Also, there might be some exceptions where it won't work but it should cover a decent percentage of use cases. We can tackle them if OP mentiones any specific cases.

Comment: The actual situation is: in a class `Message` I set a member `HashMap<String,Object>` to allow anyone which want to use `Message` can add other properties/members instead of rewriting it. Here an object may be `ArrarList<Integer>`. Here comes the problem.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you can't do that.

Unless you know that all objects that you will ever process / encounter followes certain rules, for example they allow serialization.